# Library to handle strings and numbers

Tags: library, go

I have created a pretty bad (just being honest) Golang library. I will take any and all advice, as long as it's helpful. Sorry it's so long. Also, I easily forget some things, so many functions in `convert` are just light wrappers around `strconv`, etc.

**[GitHub](https://github.com/retep-mathwizard/utils)**

#### Convert

```
package convert

import (
    "github.com/retep-mathwizard/utils/depend"
    o "github.com/retep-mathwizard/utils/other"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "math"
)

func IntToString(num int) string {
    str := strconv.Itoa(num)
    return str
}

func StringToInt(str string) int {
    num, err := strconv.Atoi(str)
    if err != nil {
        o.Exit("there was an error converting the type")
    }
    return num
}
func FloatToString(dec float64) string {
    str := strconv.FormatFloat(dec, 'f', -1, 64)
    return str
}
func StringToFloat(str string) float64 {
    dec, err := strconv.ParseFloat(str, 64)
    if err != nil {
        o.Exit("there was an error converting the type")
    }
    return dec
}

func FloatToInt(dec float64) int {
    num := int(dec)
    return num
}

func IntToFloat(num int) float64 {
    dec := float64(num)
    return dec
}
func BoolToString(boo bool) string {
    str := strconv.FormatBool(boo)
    return str
}
func StringToBool(str string) bool {
    boo, err := strconv.ParseBool(str)
    if err != nil {
        o.Exit("there was an error converting the type")
    }
    return boo
}
func StringToSlice(str string, splitat string) []string {
    stringSlice := strings.Split(str, splitat)
    return stringSlice
}
func SliceToString(array []string) string {
    str := strings.Join(array, "")
    return str

}
func IntToArray(num int) []int {
    list := []int{}
    digits := int(math.Log10(float64(num))) + 1
    for i := digits - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        list = append(list, depend.IndexInt(num, i))
    }
    return list
}
func IntArrayToStringArray(list []int) []string {
    newlist := []string{}
    for _, item := range list {
        stritem := IntToString(item)
        newlist = append(newlist, stritem)
    }
    return newlist
}
func StringArrayToIntArray(list []string) []int {
    newlist := []int{}
    for _, item := range list {
        intitem := StringToInt(item)
        newlist = append(newlist, intitem)
    }
    return newlist
}
```

#### Input

```
package input

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    c "github.com/skilstak/go/colors"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

//credit goes to @whitman
func IntInput(p string) int {
    //This function just returns whatever is typed as a integer.
    fmt.Print(c.X + p)
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    t, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(-1)
    }
    t = strings.TrimSpace(t)
    i, err := strconv.Atoi(t)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(-1)
    }
    return i
}

//credit goes to @whitman
func StringInput(messageToUser string) string {
    //This function just returns whatever is typed as a string.
    fmt.Print(c.X + messageToUser)
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    t, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(-1)
    }
    t = strings.TrimSpace(t)
    t = strings.ToLower(t)
    //takes off whitespace and makes it lowercase
    return t
}

//credit goes to @whitman
func FloatInput(messageToUser string) float64 {
    //This function just returns whatever is typed as float64, a decimal or integer.
    fmt.Print(c.X + messageToUser)
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    t, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(-1)
    }
    t = strings.TrimSpace(t)
    f, err := strconv.ParseFloat(t, 64)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(-1)
    }
    return f
}
```

#### mmath

```
package mmath

import (
    "math"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func Round(f float64) int {
    return int(math.Floor(f + .5))
}
func RandInt(low int, high int) int {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    randRoll := rand.Intn(high-low) + low
    return randRoll
}
func SumIntSlice(intslice []int) (sum int) {
    sum := 0
    for _, v := range intslice {
        sum += v
    }
    return sum
}
func SumFloat64Slice(intslice []float64) (sum float64) {
    var sum float64 = 0.0
    for _, v := range intslice {
        sum += v
    }
    return sum
}
```

#### mod

```
package mod

import (
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func RandStringItem(list []string) string {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    randNum := rand.Intn(len(list))
    randElement := list[randNum]
    return randElement
}
func RandIntItem(list []int) int {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    randNum := rand.Intn(len(list))
    randElement := list[randNum]
    return randElement
}
func ReverseStringSlice(list []string) []string {
    for i, j := 0, len(list)-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
        list[i], list[j] = list[j], list[i]
    }
    return list
}
func ReverseIntSlice(list []int) []int {
    for i, j := 0, len(list)-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
        list[i], list[j] = list[j], list[i]
    }
    return list
}
func ReverseString(s string) string {
    r := []rune(s)
    for i, j := 0, len(r)-1; i < len(r)/2; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
        r[i], r[j] = r[j], r[i]
    }
    return string(r)
}
func ReverseInt(n int) int {
    new_int := 0
    for n > 0 {
        remainder := n % 10
        new_int *= 10
        new_int += remainder
        n /= 10
    }
    return new_int
}
func Remove(slice []string, index int) []string {
    result := []string{}
    result = append(result, slice[0:index]...)
    // Append part after the removed element.
    result = append(result, slice[index+1:]...)
    return result
}
func Insert(s []string, at int, val string) []string {
    // Make sure there is enough room
    s = append(s, "0")
    // Move all elements of s up one slot
    copy(s[at+1:], s[at:])
    // Insert the new element at the now free position
    s[at] = val
    return s
}
func RemoveDuplicates(elements []string) []string {
    // Use map to record duplicates as we find them.
    encountered := map[string]bool{}
    result := []string{}

    for v := range elements {
        if encountered[elements[v]] == true {
            // Do not add duplicate.
        } else {
            // Record this element as an encountered element.
            encountered[elements[v]] = true
            // Append to result slice.
            result = append(result, elements[v])
        }
    }
    // Return the new slice.
    return result
}
func MergeStringSlice(slice1, slice2 []string) (c []string) {
    c = append(slice1, slice2...)
    return
}
func MergeIntSlice(slice1, slice2 []int) (c []int) {
    c = append(slice1, slice2...)
    return
}
func SliceContains(sl []interface{}, v interface{}) bool {
    for _, vv := range sl {
        if vv == v {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
```

#### other

```
package other

import (
    "fmt"
    c "github.com/skilstak/go/colors"
    "os"
    "reflect"
)

func PrintType(item interface{}) {
    Objecttype := reflect.TypeOf(item)
    fmt.Println(Objecttype)
}

//credit goes to @whitman
func Spacer(timesToRepeat int) {
    //draws that many blank lines
    repeat := 0
    for repeat < timesToRepeat {
        fmt.Println()
        repeat++
    }
}

func Exit(message string) {
    //prints a message and takes in whether you want to clear the screen
    fmt.Println(c.B1 + message + c.X)
    os.Exit(-1)
}

func ColorTest() {
    fmt.Println(c.R + "Red" + c.X)
    fmt.Println(c.O + "Orange" + c.X)
    fmt.Println(c.Y + "Yellow" + c.X)
    fmt.Println(c.G + "Green" + c.X)
    fmt.Println(c.C + "Cyan" + c.X)
    fmt.Println(c.B + "Blue" + c.X)
    fmt.Println(c.M + "Magenta" + c.X)
    fmt.Println(c.V + "Violet" + c.X)
    fmt.Println(c.B0 + "Base 0" + c.X)
    fmt.Println(c.B00 + "Base 00" + c.X)
    fmt.Println(c.B1 + "Base 1" + c.X)
    fmt.Println(c.B01 + "Base 01" + c.X)
    fmt.Println(c.B2 + "Base 2" + c.X)
    fmt.Println(c.B02 + "Base 02" + c.X)
    fmt.Println(c.B3 + "Base 3" + c.X)
    fmt.Println(c.B03 + "Base 03" + c.X)
    fmt.Println(c.Multi("MultiColored") + c.X)
    fmt.Println(c.Rc() + "Random" + c.X)
}
```

#### Dependent Functions

```
package depend

import "math"

func IndexInt(val, index int) int {
    if index > 0 {
        val = val / (int)(math.Pow10(index))
    }
    return val % 10
}

//things that wont work by themselves, used by other functions
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the Go programming language: [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec). Using a misnomer like Golang is like spelling and typographical errors in a resume, it's an immediate red flag.

Your packages are undocumented. See [Godoc: documenting Go code](http://blog.golang.org/godoc-documenting-go-code) and [GoDoc](https://godoc.org/).

> An [idiosyncrasy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiosyncrasy) is an unusual feature of a person. It also means
>   odd habit. The term is often used to express eccentricity or
>   peculiarity.

You confess that your libraries are idiosyncratic, which means that they and the code that uses them will be of little use to others.

**`convert`**:

You write

```
func IntToString(num int) string {
    str := strconv.Itoa(num)
    return str
}
```

which, simplified, is

```
func IntToString(i int) string {
    return strconv.Itoa(i)
}
```

It's obvious that `IntToString` is merely renaming a function from the [`strconv`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/) package in the Go standard library.

```
s = IntToString(i)
s = strconv.Itoa(i)
```

Your rationale is "I easily forget some things." That's not a problem. What is a problem is that you don't know how to easily find this information in the documentation. No employer wants employees who write idiosyncratic, unreadable, and unmaintainable code.

Similarly, you write,

```
func FloatToInt(dec float64) int {
    num := int(dec)
    return num
}
```

which, simplified, is

```
func FloatToInt(f float64) int {
    return int(f)
}
```

It's obvious that `FloatToInt` is merely performing an `int` conversion.

```
i = FloatToInt(f)
i = int(f)
```

I see negative value in your idosyncratic Go standard library function wrappers.

Similarly the `input`, `mmath`, `mod`, `other`, and `depend` packages seem idiosyncratic.

Comment: People often informally call it "Golang" because "Go" is awkward as a noun and difficult to Google.

Comment: @200_success: That, and a dozen other excuses :-(

Comment: Excellent answer. Couldn't agree more.